# Execute a command only on a specific candlestick

Tags: pine-script

This is The first and last my code

I want to run the code `CO = false` for the first time in the script, but it will never be executed again, that is it will not be calculated in any of the other candlesticks

My goal :
I will not receive error in `if (CO and CLW)` in the first run

Objective of the program: first one condition is set, it gets true, then it waits until the candle that gives the next condition true (ie the two conditions are not one candle)

```
CO = false
if (crossover (vrsi, overSold))
     CO = true
...

continue the code

...
if (CO and CLW)
     strategy.entry ("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment = "RsiLE")
     CO = false
```

‌

Answer (score 0):

By using the `var` keyword to declare `CO`, it will retain it's value across bars until you modify it.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#op_var

```
var bool CO = false
if (crossover (vrsi, overSold))
     CO := true
...

continue the code

...

if (CO and CLW)
     strategy.entry ("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment = "RsiLE")
     CO := false
```